# GWT: Masking a widget

Tags: gwt, popup, mask, masking

I want to mask a widget. So i used a popup panel to do the same

```
public class MyMask extends PopupPanel
{
public MyMask ()
{
    super();
}

public void showAbsolute( UIObject uiObject )
{
    show();
    setPopupPosition( uiObject.getAbsoluteLeft(), uiObject.getAbsoluteTop() );
}
```

}

and my mask class looks like this

```
public final class Mask
{
private static MyMask mask = new MyMask();
private static UIObject object;

private Mask()
{
}

public static void enable( UIObject uiObject )
{
    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    vp.setVerticalAlignment( HasVerticalAlignment.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
    vp.setStyleName( "mask" );
    vp.setHeight( uiObject.getOffsetHeight() + Unit.PX.getType() );
    vp.setWidth( uiObject.getOffsetWidth() + Unit.PX.getType() );
    mask.add( vp );
    mask.showAbsolute( uiObject );
}

public static void disable()
{
    mask.hide();
}
}
```

But by calling

```
Mask.enable(widget)
```

The popup panel is not appearing exactly over the widget instead its coming below the widget and little bit towards the left. I want it to appear exactly on the widget. Any idea how to go about it?

Am currently using gwt 2.4.0

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot how your masked panel looks like?

Comment: I posted the screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple... No need of popup panel. Just change it disabled state and turn the background color to gray on mask and enable it, reapply the style on unmask

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against this approach in the first place, since it is not standard GUI practice, and all input widgets let you call `setEnabled(false)` on them anyhow to prevent user input.

Comment: I have a situation here for which i need to take the following approach... If you have any ideas please share it

Comment: I *think* the amount of horizontal and vertical scrolling of the browser window might have something to do with it. Check the values for `Window.getScrollLeft` and `Window.getScrollTop`. I think you have to adjust the coordinates of your panel with these values.

Comment: Pity... If your panel is consistenly the same amount of pixels 'off', then you might tweak its position with style attributes, i.e. shift the margins until it is positioned properly. Bit of an hack though :) 
Would also be good to inspect the browser output with firebug and actually see what css attributes are applied. Good luck!